# Is checking the Thread is "UI Thread" before Calling Dispatcher.Invoke redundant?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, ui-thread

In regards to

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

I have looked at `CheckAccess()` and various ways of determining whether i'm on the main UI thread. Though after looking at the [Dispatcher Source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,602) for `Invoke`, it seems to call `CheckAccess()` and performs other checks anyway

**Invoke Source Code**

```
public void Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
{
   ...
   ...

   // Fast-Path: if on the same thread, and invoking at Send priority,
   // and the cancellation token is not already canceled, then just
   // call the callback directly.
   if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && priority == DispatcherPriority.Send && CheckAccess())
   {
      SynchronizationContext oldSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

      try
      {
         DispatcherSynchronizationContext newSynchronizationContext;
         if (BaseCompatibilityPreferences.GetReuseDispatcherSynchronizationContextInstance())
         {
            newSynchronizationContext = _defaultDispatcherSynchronizationContext;
         }
         else
         {
            if (BaseCompatibilityPreferences.GetFlowDispatcherSynchronizationContextPriority())
            {
               newSynchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(this, priority);
            }
            else
            {
               newSynchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(this, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
            }
         }
         SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(newSynchronizationContext);

         callback();
         ...
```

So the most reliable way to check whether my dialog needs to be invoked is by calling `Invoke`? looking at `CheckAccess` and `SynchronisationContexts` solutions when i dont have access to a `Control` seem to be redundant.

Is this the case or is there some edge cases i'm missing, or hidden performance hit i cant see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it depends.

If you're mainly after correctness and/or code brevity, then yes, the call is redundant - calling

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

will be functionally equivalent<sup>*1*</sup> to

```
if(Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    action();
else
    Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

If however your concern is performance, then it's not so obvious. [`CheckAccess`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs.html#853a67ef85de632f) literally reads

```
return Thread == Thread.CurrentThread;
```

so even if it's called twice as many times, it will hardly be noticeable. `Dispatcher.Invoke` however does some additional work, such as argument checking and, possibly, swapping synchronization context, so I guess it potentially has larger overhead than a redundant call to `CheckAccess()`. But, as usual with performance optimization, there's no single right answer - it depends on your particular case (for example on the likelihood of this code being called from non-UI thread).

---

*1 Obviously there may be additional things happening with the synchronization context when calling* `Dispatcher.Invoke`*, but unless* `action` *is making use of it, the result will be the same*

Comment: The particular use case is that its just unknown if the thread is UI, long story short its basically a global error handler for a last ditch effort to alert the user through a dialog. however thanks for the detailed response